# No puedo hacer que una interfaz desaparezca

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola estoy haciendo haciendo un proyecto en NetBeans con varios *frames* y usé el `.setvisible(true);` que me funciona correctamente para que aparezcan mis otras interfaces; pero también usé el `.setVisible(null);` para que desaparezca la interfaz anterior pero sigue apareciendo detrás de la otra. No tengo nada de código programado más que eso; no tengo errores ni nada y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Hola @Mariana, seria bueno que pusieses el código relevante que lleves hasta ahora.

Comment: Bienvenido Mariana ! Te aconsejo que agregues tu código como se describe en [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Puede leer tambien [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tenía cierta lógica pensar que el método, si acepta un booleano positivo, requiere un booleano negativo para tu caso. Puedes consultar la *doc de Java* para estas dudas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con siguiente solución. En lugar de usar `.setVisible(null);` usa lo siguiente:

`JFrame.setVisible(false);`